# Setting up mod_proxy to pass http authentication to server

Tags: apache, proxy, credentials, http-authentication

I have a problem configuring Apache as a proxy server. At the moment I access a MS Sharepoint installation using domain.net over Port 80. Before being able to use it I have to enter username and password. So far so good.

Now I want to be able to access a website over a subdomain web.domain.net. The Server hosting this site runs on another machine in the internal network. The solution I came up with is to redirect port 80 to the machine running apache to serve the new website and proxy any requests for the sharepoint to the sharepoint server.

So far I enabled all the proxy modules in my httpd.conf and added a virtual host.
**EDIT: Updated config after first responses.**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.net

    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyErrorOverride On
    ProxyPass   /   http://sharepoint/
    ProxyPassReverse   /   http://sharepoint/

    <Location />
        AuthType basic
        AuthBasicAuthoritative Off
        SetEnv proxy-chain-auth On
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

This works. Entering domain.net forwards me to the sharepoint server. Now comes the actually problem. The sharepoint asks me for my credentials. But when I enter them the login form keeps popping up as I entered no or incorrect username and password.

It seems like the credentials aren't forwarded to the sharepoint through the proxy.

Can you give me any advise how to solve this? Is it possible to do this using mod_proxy?

Comment: Did you ever get this working? We're looking at a similar problem and wondered what the solution was.

Comment: @x3ja Actually I gave it up after some days and just went with using different ports and configured my router such that port 80 is redirect to the sharepoint server and 8080 to the subdomain-hosting server. If you come up with a solution, let me know. I'm still interested in solving this elegant.

Answer (score 9):

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_http.html: there is a `proxy-chain-auth` environmental variable that should forward the credentials on to the proxied server.

Comment: Does it matter where I do the
    SetEnv proxy-chain-auth On
? I added it in the <VirtualHost> Tag but nothing changed after restarting the apache.

Comment: Ah, I don't think it does: anywhere in the VirtualHost section should work. However, you may need to fit in `AuthType`/`AuthName` settings to force the username/password to be expected by Apache. If you do that you may want to use the `AuthBasicAuthoritative Off` setting as described at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_auth_basic.html to make sure Apache knows to just pass it on if it can't find it. Might get messy though...

Comment: Sounded quite promising, nontheless it's not working :( I updated the configuration in my original question to what it is at the moment. I would appreciate every further help.

Comment: Hmm. I'll try this later on today: try putting the `SetEnv Proxy-Chain-Auth On` inside the Location block.

Comment: Okay, I did a little more research on this and found, that the actual server does NTLM authentication. Can this be handled by apache? Like `AuthType NTLM`...
Perhaps I should add, that I'm on a Windows machine.

Comment: Ah, NTLM is very poorly supported: you may be out of luck there.

Comment: Seems so... I tried some NTLM modules, non of them worked. So I have to go with the solution of running the to services on different ports. Thanks for your help @femi!

Comment: Proxy-chain-auth works only on the `Proxy-Authorization` header.